# Android 8.1 lock screen credential screenshot disabled by app

Tags: android, screenshot, lockscreen

My app stores something in the Android Keystore with Lock Screen protection.

To get the user to authenticate, I call   [KeyguardManager.createConfirmDeviceCredentialIntent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/KeyguardManager.html#createConfirmDeviceCredentialIntent(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence)) and use startActivityForResult with the Intent.

On previous versions of Android, I can take a screenshot of the lock screen dialog that appears. When I try on Android 8, I get a notification that says

> **Couldn't capture screenshot.**
>   Taking screenshots isn't allowed by the app or your organization

I am able to take a screenshot of the "normal" lock screen when unlocking the device, and also in the settings when changing the lock screen. So I don't think it's my "organization" preventing me.

How can I configure my app to allow screenshots to be taken on this screen?

Solutions I found on the web say to rename the Pictures directory on the device storage to Pictures2, but that solution didn't work for me. I have encountered this issue on the Google Pixel and the Nexus 5X.

Answer (score 0):

Android app has specified FLAG_SECURE specified.  The app itself is preventing screenshots
 https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_SECURE

Comment: I have not referenced FLAG_SECURE anywhere in my app. Is there somewhere I can override this flag for the lock screen prompt?